# Decomposition of a real number in base $b$

Tags: arithmetic

We've had a class today about decomposing a real number in base $b$ and saw the following theorem :

> Let $b\in\mathbb{N},b\geq2$.
>
> For all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$, there exists a unique sequence
>   $a\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such as:
>
> - $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^*,a_k\in[|0,b-1|]$
> - $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{b^k}\leq x\leq\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{b^k}+\frac{1}{b^n}$
> - $a$ isn't stationary to $b-1$ (*ie* there is no $n_0$ such that $a_{k\geq n_0}=b-1$)
>
> $(a_k)_\mathbb{N}$ is called the development of $x$ in the base $b$
>
> $x=\overline{a_0,a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ is the b-adic decomposition of $x$.

The first two points can be proved quite easily by building the sequence from scratch

$a_0=\lfloor x\rfloor$ in base $b$ and $a_{n+1}=\lfloor b^{n+1}\left(x-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{b^k}\right)\rfloor$.

However, how can the 3rd point be proven easily ?

We went through a really *really* long proof in class, and i feel like there is an easier way.

Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to correct any English mistake I might have made.

Comment: I think this is the $1=0.9999...$ equality (and its correspondent in other bases) being referenced.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Exactly, n°3 is supposed to prevent this kind of decomposition - I still have to prove it holds

Comment: Unfortunately by constructing $a_i$ to be a floor, I think you're ensuring that you'll get the $b-1$-stationary form rather than the other one, so what you need to show is that $0.\overline{b-1}_b = 1$, and that generalizes to other numbers with repeating $b-1$'s.